# Trying to shorten Lua code

Tags: lua, logitech

Is there a way to shorten this code?

```
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
PressKey ("a")
Sleep (50)
if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
ReleaseKey ("a")
return
end
PressKey ("a")
Sleep (200)
if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
ReleaseKey ("a")
return
end
...
next all the same with sleep values only changing
```

I want to use the repeat-until, but I cant do that as the value for sleep is changing. Is there a way to save the sleep values in a table (ie. 50, 200, 100, 75, 25, 200) so I can use the Repeat-Until in the code? I've been trying to search but I am new to Lua. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to loop over a range of timeouts I wouldn't use `repeat until` but rather a `for` loop.  Most importantly you should notify the caller that all timeouts failed after finishing the list.

```
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
    for _,duration in ipairs{50, 200, 100, 75, 25, 200} do
        PressKey ("a")
        Sleep (duration)
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            ReleaseKey ("a")
            return
        end
    end
    return "ERROR" -- You should somehow indicate timeout to the caller
end
```